# Maintain src/ folder structure when building to dist/ folder with TypeScript 3

Tags: typescript, build, tsc, transpiler

I have a TypeScript nodejs server with this structure:

```
tsconfig.json
package.json
src/
    middleware/
    utils/
    index.ts
dist/
    middleware/
    utils/
    index.js
```

When using TypeScript 2, I was able to transpile my project from the src/ to a dist/ folder and have a mirror image of my directory structure to work with.

With the release of TypeScript 3, they have introduced [project references](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/07/30/announcing-typescript-3-0/#project-references) and changed the way code is transpiled into an output directory. Now `tsc` outputs to the dist/ folder in a nested way like this:

```
dist/
    src/
        middleware/
        utils/
        index.js
```

My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "lib": [
      "es7",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/"
  ]
}
```

How can I configure TypeScript to output my src/ folder as a mirror image into a dist/ folder?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I had a similar problem when initially converting to a TypeScript project. I also set `resolveJsonModule: true` and the `src` directory was copied to the output `dist` directory.

The underlying reason is that one of my source files `require`d package.json at the root of the project. Once I removed that, tsc no longer added src to the dist directory.

**In short, make sure you are not requiring files outside of your src directory.**

Explanatory FAQ here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-does---outdir-moves-output-after-adding-a-new-file

Comment: It works! But why? Why does `resolveJsonModule` make `tsc` output to `/dist/src` instead of `/dist` ? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @s.meijer because it enables the importing `package.json` (a "JsonModule"), and that forces `rootDir` to automatically get set to the directory that contains all the source (i.e. including `package.json`), and now the `src` dir is no longer the rootDir but a subdir, and so reflected in the output. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467483/8910547 for more info and links to what Typescript's bossman says about it.

Comment: thanks for this. it also produces the same output when you want to have a structure such as ./src/ and ./typings but wish not to have ./src in your ./dist ... long story short, as long as you reference ./typings in ./src, it will be included and so ./src will be kept. T_T

Comment: In my case it was `"include": ["**/*.ts"]` -> `"include": ["src/**/*.ts"]` in the `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: You might also be able to solve your problem by using the `require` syntax over `import`. In my case I was importing a service-account.json, and changing the `import` to `require` allowed my ts build to output correctly.

Comment: In my case I had to add the `migrations` folder to be excluded in the exclude array within `tsconfig.json`..migrations folder had all the database related `ALTER table` migration scripts

Answer (score 73):

The structure of the output directory is controlled by the `rootDir` of the `compilerOptions`. [See documentation here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), setting it to `./src` should solve the issue.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    ...
  },
  "include": [
    "src/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Actually it will just swap problems in this case. The OP is importing `package.json`, so if you change the `rootDir` to `src`, you'll get the right `outDir` structure, but a compilation error because you have source outside of `rootDir`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467483/8910547 for more info and links to what Typescript's bossman says about it.

Comment: using `rootDir` solved the issue for me with a local `.ts` library I was importing

Comment: i get Inigos mentioned issue - fix on src not in dist anymore, but a compile issue :o(

Answer (score 24):

The upgrade from TypeScript 2 to 3 by itself shouldn't have changed the behavior; if we can confirm that it did, that may be a bug.  In any case, check that the `rootDir` compiler option points to your `src` directory and not to the parent directory, because the structure under the `rootDir` is what is mirrored under the `outDir`.

Comment: I've added my tsconfig.json to help clarify. The project is configured around using the `"include"` key to specify the src/ directory. I just confirmed that the Typescript 2 compiler will simply mirror src/ into dist/ with this configuration, but the Typescript 3 compiler will automatically include the package.json and the src/ folder nested with dist/.

Attempts to point `rootDir` at src/ fail because the package.json file isn't in there.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior based on the information you've provided.  If you can publish a repository that reproduces the problem, I will look.  Otherwise, I can only suggest that you try deleting things from your project until the problem goes away and then you'll see what's causing it.

Comment: I was able to determine the cause. It seems that adding the `resolveJsonModule: true` to my tsconfig.json was causing tsc to output the dist/ directory differently. I'm still not entirely clear on why it does that, but it does seem to be a talking point in a few Github issues: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25216 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24744

Thank you for your help Matt!

Comment: This is not at all clear from the [compiler-options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) page.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to specifying `compilerOptions.outDir`, specify `compilerOptions.rootDir` in `tsconfig.json`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     // ...
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "./",
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then run: `$ tsc -b` inside the folder where the `tsconfig.json` file is.

**Note**: the `compilerOptions.rootDir` should be used when you wish include a structure of files of an non-nested folder in the folder of `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: What does the -b flag do? Can't find docs --build and --baseUrl as in there, but no --b

Comment: Sorry for late. The `-b` flag is a alias to [--build flag](https://tsplay.dev/tsc-build).

Comment: Thanks for this! it works. You could also set the `"composite": true` option in tsconfig.json instead of using the `-b` command line flag.

Comment: I didn't know that. I'll try it. Thanks. Just run the `tsc` command in this case?

Comment: @CraigWayne sorry, but that doesn't work properly. The `-b` flag is necessary when we use line command.

Answer (score 5):

I've used a symlink to accomplish this. It neatly allows you to reference root-level files without referencing them directly. For example:

1. From `/src`, create a link to package.json:

```
ln -s ../package.json ./details.json
```

2. Refer to `details.json` in your TypeScript file:

```
import { version } from './details.json';

exports.handler = async function ( event: Event ) {
  console.log( `lambda version v${version}` );
```

3. Bask in the grandeur of `dist`'s flattened file structure:

```
$ tsc

$ tree dist 
dist
├── index.d.ts
├── index.js
└── details.json

0 directories, 3 files
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to compile a typescript file at `/scr/mydir/hello.ts` to `/dist/mydir/hello.js` but the file keeps getting created at `/dist/hello.js`, what you can do is to add another typescript file at `/src/another.ts`. That way the two compiled files will go to `/src/another.js` and `/src/mydir/hello.js`. Rememver, in your `tsconfig.json`, `outDir` must be set to `./dist`

Answer (score 1):

In case you have multiple entries under the `include` option, make sure they are resolved.

```
"include": ["src", "tests"],
```

For example, if `tests` is not found, the `src` directory will not be present in the `outDir`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that including one more folder, such as `spec` with test files would resolve the issue as well. This does not respond the original question, but I found it interesting to mention in the context.

Answer (score 0):

and also enable allowJs property, setting it to true. Then, all files others .js files is copied, replicating all structure of src dir to dist dir.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#allowJs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. In the tsconfig.json file, you need to specify the output directory, for instance **"outDir": "./dist",**. The reason you have several folders in the dist folder is because you have two folders in the root which are compile and pasted in the dist folder. You can specify in the tsconfig.json **"rootDir": "./src"** thereafter only **src folder** will be considered.

Answer (score 0):

set the "outDir": "./dist",  in tsconfig.json

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

you can change file import from ***src/entities/Post   ->  ../entities/Post***  in file in ./src

this changes the import in the dist folder.