# How to remove the src folder (flatten) when transpiling with nx (tsc)?

Tags: typescript, nrwl-nx, transpiler

I made a lib project using NX here : https://github.com/geofmigliacci/magnetarise so I can transpile & I get my dist folder like so :

```
dist/core/src
```

The thing is that when I pack my project and install it, when I want to import I get an import like so :

```
import { XService } from '@magnetarise/src/services';
```

But I'd like to have an import like :

```
import { XService } from '@magnetarise/services'; (not everything inside @magnetarise)
```

So removing the src folder ; I already took a look at [Maintain src/ folder structure when building to dist/ folder with TypeScript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121725/maintain-src-folder-structure-when-building-to-dist-folder-with-typescript-3) & tried to set the rootDir to "src" inside my `packages/core/tsconfig.lib.json` but it doesn't work.

Has anyone got this problem & know how to solve it ?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2):

Need to `rootDir` inside `options` of project.json file

https://nx.dev/packages/js/executors/tsc#rootdir